# Error while automatically deploying angular project on Azure with Jenkins

Tags: angular, azure, jenkins

please can you help me to fix my problem.

I am trying to deploy automatically angular project on Azure with Jenkins, but I am getting error as it is on photo, inside the logs of azure that is everything ok, we can see that the build is done with success, but on Jenkins I am getting error.

Thanks

Comment: could you please add more details and attach screen shot of error.

Comment: Hello Manoj, this is what we got error

https://ibb.co/m5yRJ1k